# How to print one of dictonary values with specialized letter

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I'm starting with Python.
I have the problem, because code not work like i want  to do.
My target is to print for example if x = a i want to print 3. Is it possible to do without much effort?

```
dictonary1 = {
'a':3,
'b':4,
'c':5,
}

x = str(input("input a letter"))
for x in dictonary1:
    print(x in dictonary1)
```

Now i get for all of keys

```
True
True
True
```

Comment: There is no need for a loop here. Just do `if x in dictionary1: print dictionary1[x]`. Also, `input` returns a string, so there is no need for a `str(...)` around it.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to print (or use) a dictionary key if you are not sure it exists is:

```
print(dictonary1.get(x))
```

This way, if it doesn't exist, it will print (or produce) `None`, while if you use `dictionary1[x]` and the key doesn't exist, you will get an error.

Comment: This will output `None` in case the key doesn't exist, which is **not** what the OP wants.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I don't see where he wrote what he wants if the key doesn't exist, and I speficially wrote in the answer that he will get `None` if it doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you, i hope it helps:

```
answer=None
dictionary1 = { 'a':3, 'b':4, 'c':5, }
while answer==None:
   try:
      x = input("input a letter: ")
      answer = dictionary1.get(x)
      print(f"Dictionary answer to {x} is {answer}")
   except:
      answer=None
```

Comment: I believe you meant to write: `answer = dictionary1[x]`, because the way you wrote it, there will never be an exception, so the `try... except` is redundant.